# checkbox oncheck javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

I have a checkbox That I need to show a div when it is clicked.  I have 3 different javascripts that i have attempted to get this to work with.

```
//function showhide() {
//    var checkbox = document.getElementById("assist");
//    var expanded1 = document.getElementById("expanded");
//    var expanded2 = document.getElementById("expanded2");

//    expanded1.style.visibility = (expanded1.style.visibility == 'false') ? "true" : "false";
//    alert('test');
//}
function(){
var checkbox = document.getElementById("assist");
var expanded1 = document.getElementById("expanded");
var expanded2 = document.getElementById("expanded2");
checkbox.onchange = function () {
    expanded1.style.visibility = this.checked ? 'true' : 'false';
    alert('test');

}
//function check() {
//    $('chk').click(function () {
//        if (this.checked) {
//            $("#expanded").show();
//            $("#expanded2").show();
//        }
//        else {
//            $("#expanded").hide();
//            $("#expanded2").hide();
//        }
//    });
//}
```

This is the checkbox below.

```
<input type="checkbox" runat="server" id="assist"  onclick="showhide();" /></div>
```

The divs that need to be shown/hidden are expanded and expanded2.

I cannot get the javascript functions to be hit from the checkbox could someone tell me what is wrong.

Comment: `true` and `false` aren't valid values for the `visibility` property, so that's probably your problem

Comment: What on earth is a nameless `function()` doing over there?

Comment: Your code with showHide works fine for me: http://jsfiddle.net/nivas/wrn42/

Comment: i guess the showhide get hit but i am getting a style is set to null error

Answer (score 1):

Use the `window.onload` event to assign the change handler and remove the inline `onclick` from the HTML. Also the visibility CSS should be `visible` or `hidden`.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bX2ZG/)

```
window.onload = function () {
    var checkbox = document.getElementById("assist");
    var expanded1 = document.getElementById("expanded");
    checkbox.onchange = function () {
        expanded1.style.visibility = this.checked ? 'visible' : 'hidden';
    };
};
```

Comment: It is definatly hitting this function but i am getting an cannot set property onchange to null error.

Comment: Sounds like your code isn't running in the `window.onload` event if the element is null.

Comment: I can get it to hit my showhide function. Which would happen after all the elements are loaded. I also get that error for that.

Answer (score 0):

For Hiding the DIV using Jquery you can try below code:

instead of this.checked use `$(this).is(':checked')`

```
 $('.chk').click( function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    if( $this.is(':checked') == true ) {
       $("#div1").show();        
    }  else {
       $("#div1").hide();

    }    
});
```

Answer (score 0):

html

```
 <input type="checkbox" runat="server" id="assist"  onclick="showhide();" />



            <div class="required1" id="mycheckboxdiv1" style="display:none" >
                your code;
            </div>
```

this will do for u :)
jquery

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#mycheckboxdiv1').hide();

    $('#assist').click(function(){


            if($('#assist').is(':checked')){

                        $('#mycheckboxdiv1').toggle();
              }
          else 
              {
                $('#mycheckboxdiv1').hide();

              }
       });

});

</script>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/maree_chaudhry/QmXCV/ here is fiddle

Answer (score 0):

You're already using jQuery, so you could just use:

```
$("#assist").change(function(){
   $("#expanded, #expanded2").toggle();
});
```

[**jsFiddle here**](http://jsfiddle.net/svmY3/3/)

Comment: $("#assist").change(function () {
        $("#expanded, #expanded2").css('display', this.checked ? 'block' : 'none');
        alert('test');
    });

I changed the visibility to display and it is not working correctly.  I added jquery to the top of my file also

Comment: @user3494929 Put it inside $(document).ready(function(){ ...  })

Comment: $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#assist").change(function () {
            $("#expanded, #expanded2").css('display', this.checked ? 'block' : 'none');
            alert('test');
        });
    });

Like this? It is still not doing anything on the click of the checkbox.

Comment: @user3494929 Can you show me a jsFiddle example of it not working? I can't solve the problem if I don't have enough info about the problem itself.

Comment: @user3494929 Let me know if my answer helped by 'ticking' it as correct :) thanks

Comment: I see that works correctly for you. Even though i Have hte exact same code on my front end. It will hit hte document load for me. Then on the change will hit but never actually toggles the divs for me.